# Different return value of 'for' loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am new to JavaScript. Now I am facing an issue in a `for` loop.

The statement I wrote:

```
var name = ["John", "Lee", "Alex"];
for( ; x < name.length -1; x++){
    document.write(name[x]);}
```

I should get the result `John, Lee`, but I won't.

Comment: Debug Debug, Console, Console: undeclared variable `x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undeclared variable `x` and the most important: **you're using the window attribute `name`**, so that variable will be cast to String.

- Declare the variable `x`.
- Change the identifier of that array to `names` for example.

```js
var names = ["John", "Lee", "Alex"];
for (var x = 0; x < names.length - 1; x++) {
  document.write(names[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the declaration for the var `i` in your loop syntax right where I put empty quotes:

```
var name = ["John", "Lee", "Alex" ];
    for(" ";x < name.length -1;x++ ){
        document.write(name[x]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var name = ["John", "Lee", "Alex"];
for (var x = 0; x < name.length - 1; x++) {
  document.write(name[x]);
}
```

Where the `for` loop declares the variable `x` with initial value `0`

Comment: I tried your suggestion,but i shown me:
      //return 
"John,Lee,Ale"

Comment: var names = ["John", "Lee", "Alex"];
var result = names.join(',');
return result;

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable x, so you can use it:

```
 var name = ["John", "Lee", "Alex" ];
    for(var x= 0;x < name.length -1;x++ ){
        document.write(name[x]);
   }
```